# Estimate distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given the following probability distributions $p(X|D)$, $p(Y|D)$ and $p(X, Y)$ what are the ways to estimate $p(X, Y| D)$?

This question arose from practical problem, so I don't pretend on exact solution, but rather some decent approximation (maybe with some additional assumptions). Here $D$ states for data and $X, Y$ are predictions.